How do i fix the mongoose sorting function?
I am trying to sort my data according to its prices. It says its successful but the data is empty. I think something with the query variables or with the sort function. When I try querying with no sort, the tour variable have data. How to make the tours have data in it?
  try {
    //1) Basic Filtering
    const queryObj = { ...req.query };
    const excludedFields = ['limit', 'sort', 'page', 'fields'];
    excludedFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObj[el]);

    //2) Advanced Filtering
    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(req.query);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);

    let query = Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

    //3) Sorting
    if (req.query.sort) {
      const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
      query = query.sort(sortBy);
    } else {
      query = query.sort('price');
    }

    // Execute Query
    const tours = await query;
    console.log(tours);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      result: tours.length,
      data: {
        tours,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
};````



Do you get documents when you just do query = query.sort('price'); and then const tours = await query;

Try logging queryStr and sortBy right before they are used so you can see exactly what is being submitted.
